# jquery slideshow won't work because file attribution might be wrong

Tags: jquery, slideshow, lightbox2

I recently launched some web pages using a jquery slideshow plugin which, of course, was working just fine on my hard drive. But now that the pages are on the server, I keep seeing an error code that the 'mygallery' file is undefined. I fixed this by pointing to the public folder location where the files are located but the script still does not work. This is my first live testing. This is one of many problems. My question is whether or not I have set my attributions incorrectly?.

Update.

I pointed the program at my local directory containing the necessary images. I all worked out. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your calls for the slideshow scripts are wrong:

<script type="text/javascript">Homepage_files/imagefader.min.js</script>
<script type="text/javascript">Homepage_files/fadeslideshow.js</script>

your missing the src="" and closing the script tags too early. it should be like

<script type="text/javascript" src="Homepage_files/imagefader.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Homepage_files/fadeslideshow.js"></script>

Comment: thank you. I spent so much time changing things I screwed up a lot of what was working before. Good spot

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand why your imagearray options are defined as an array inside an array:

imagearray: [["image1.jpg"],]"image2.jpg"]]

This would be more logical:

imagearray: ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg"]

Comment: I think the arrays are that way because the image files load on top of each other.

Comment: Quazi - Your <style> declaration should be in the <head> of your document. You are using a Jquery plugin? But the page has no jquery library loaded. :)